# Breaking strings in a column by using a sliding window in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, split, sliding-window

How can I break each string in below column by using a sliding window in PostgreSQL.

Input

```
Column
TTTTACAATATAGCCAC
TTTGAAGAAAACATGCA
TTTCATACGGCTAGCGG
TTTAGTCTGTATGCTTG
```

For first string the expected output is below (sliding window = 9). I am expecting such output for every string of the column.

Output

```
TTTTACAAT
TTTACAATA
TTACAATAT
TACAATATA
ACAATATAG
CAATATAGC
AATATAGCC
ATATAGCCA
TATAGCCAC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generate_series` function is your friend here.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html

Firstly you will need to split your string as such

```
WITH split AS(
    SELECT generate_series(1, length('TTTTACAATATAGCCAC') - 8) AS start
)
SELECT substring('TTTTACAATATAGCCAC', split.start, 9)
FROM split;
```

Then, assuming you are getting it from a table, your query would go something like this.

```
WITH split AS(
    SELECT
        your_table_column as text,
        generate_series(1, length(your_table_column) - 8) AS start
    FROM your_table_name
)
SELECT substring(text, split.start, 9)
FROM split;
```

This will not display any columns that are below 9 characters, so other logic will need to be applied.